# Socket client does not terminate

Tags: java

Why the client code does not terminate? (We need to start the server program first before running the client)

**Server Code:**

```
public class ServerSocketTest {

    static final int PORT = 9999;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    serverSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        while (true) {
            final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println(socket);
                }
            };
            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
        }

    }

}
```

**Client code:**

```
public class SocketClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException,
            IOException {
        final Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", ServerSocketTest.PORT);

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("waiting to close socket " );
                printThread(Thread.currentThread());
                try {                   
                    socket.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("waiting to exit");
                printThread(Thread.currentThread());                
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    static void printThread(Thread currentThread) {
        System.out.println(currentThread + ": Alive=" + currentThread.isAlive()
                + ",Daemon=" + currentThread.isDaemon());
    }
}
```

---

I use Ubuntu. Using jconsole, I could trace the following threads plus some other RMI & JMX threads:

---

Name: Reference Handler
State: WAITING on java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock@14f38ff
Total blocked: 1  Total waited: 2

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
```

---

Name: Finalizer
State: WAITING on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@3037a0
Total blocked: 1  Total waited: 2

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:177)
```

---

Name: Signal Dispatcher
State: RUNNABLE
Total blocked: 0  Total waited: 0

Stack trace:

---

Name: DestroyJavaVM
State: WAITING on net.SocketClient$2@39b27b
Total blocked: 0  Total waited: 1

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1258)
java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1332)
java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.runHooks(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:106)
java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks$1.run(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:46)
java.lang.Shutdown.runHooks(Shutdown.java:123)
java.lang.Shutdown.sequence(Shutdown.java:167)
java.lang.Shutdown.shutdown(Shutdown.java:234)
- locked java.lang.Class@127bd04
```

---

Name: Thread-1 (This is the shutdown hook I added to invoke System.exit)
State: BLOCKED on java.lang.Class@127bd04 owned by: DestroyJavaVM
Total blocked: 1  Total waited: 0

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.Shutdown.exit(Shutdown.java:212)
java.lang.Runtime.exit(Runtime.java:107)
java.lang.System.exit(System.java:960)
net.SocketClient$2.run(SocketClient.java:31)
```

---

Name: SIGINT handler(This seems to be spwaned when Control+C is pressed)
State: BLOCKED on java.lang.Class@127bd04 owned by: DestroyJavaVM
Total blocked: 1  Total waited: 0

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.Shutdown.exit(Shutdown.java:212)
java.lang.Terminator$1.handle(Terminator.java:52)
sun.misc.Signal$1.run(Signal.java:212)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'client code does not terminate'? It seems your client doesn't even establish the connection.

Comment: It seems that calling System.exit(status) from any shutdown hook will lead to deadlock between that thread and DestroyJavaVM thread. Also between SIGINT handler(if Control+C pressed) thread and DestroyJavaVM thread.Off course, it hardly make sense to invoke System.exit(status) when shutdown has already been initiated.

Comment: hm... very interesting. could you please open your task manager and see how many threads does your client spawn?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't stop because you have live threads running, (your hooks). Or do you mean that you can't stop it even after sending a SIGTERM or SIGINT signal to the java process?

Comment: Why the hook won't terminate as they are not assigned any non-terminating task. Even Ctrl+C(SIGINT) can not stop it. I needed to issue kill -9

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I see the point of using `addShutdownHook` here. From the documentation:

> Shutdown hooks should also finish their work quickly. When a program invokes exit the expectation is that the virtual machine will promptly shut down and exit. When the virtual machine is terminated due to user logoff or system shutdown the underlying operating system may only allow a fixed amount of time in which to shut down and exit. It is therefore inadvisable to attempt any user interaction or to perform a long-running computation in a shutdown hook.

Certainly there is no need to `socket.close()` on termination because the OS will automatically do that for you if your code didn't get a chance to close it. I would try to reformulate your code without using shutdown hooks at all.

Comment: What are the resources (like socket) which are automatically released by the OS?

Comment: Opened files, window handles, sockets, pipes(when all processes which were using the pipe are terminated), etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response. DO know some site(s) where the exhaustive list of such resources (along with the exceptional cases) is documented. All such resources must be local, right? Can the OS track, the network resources(like remote Database, MQ etc.) those are acquired by a certain process?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: The OS doesn't need to track any of the remote resources. You use a socket to communicate with the remote servers, and when your process closes, the OS closes the socket for you (if you haven't already). The server (DB, MQ, whatever) will get a notification that the socket has been closed, and clean up its own world based on your client going away.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call System.exit() in a shutdown hook, and you most certainly should not do so, as it will probably produce either a deadlock or an infinite recursion. You don't need the other ones either. It would be better to make your threads daemon threads.

Comment: I've already reached that point:" it hardly make sense to invoke System.exit(status) when shutdown has already been initiated.". But if deadlock occurs, what is the shared resource? Can you definitely tell me or share me any reference? Did you perceive any change of behaviour making the shutdown hooks as daemon?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I'm sorry to disillusion you but this is not a debugging service and I have not executed your code. And I wasn't suggesting to make your shutdown hooks daemon Threads: they are Runnables, so making them daemons has zero effect. I was suggesting to get rid of these redundant shutdown hooks completely and make the remaining threads daemons.